# how do I get my bootstrap form to be showed horizontally?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

my question is about forms in bootstrap.

I had to convert from bootstrap v3 to v4. Now my form keeps showing vertically. What do I need to do to get it horizontally?

[screenshot of what it looked like in bootstrap 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNUOi.jpg)

my code:

```
<div class="col-4">
    <form method="post" action="index_s.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row["product_id"]; ?>">
        <div style="border:1px solid #333; background-color:#f1f1f1; border-radius:15px; padding:20px;" align="center">
            <img src="<?php echo $row["product_image"]; ?>" class="img-fluid" /><br />
            <h4 class="text-info"><?php echo $row["product_name"]; ?></h4>
            <h4 class="text-danger">€ <?php echo $row["product_price"]; ?></h4>
            <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-conrol" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["product_name"]; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row["product_price"]; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="In winkelwagen" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

if anyone could help me, that would be fantastic!
thanks for considering my request

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing how it looked in Bootstrap 3 for you? The layout looks the same between the both versions for me.

Comment: I've added a picture to the original post!

Answer (score 0):

I have used bootstrap 4 and slightly modified your markup to produce a very similar result to your screenshot. I also removed PHP blocks for the purpose of the snippet.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <form method="post" action="">
        <div style="border:1px solid #333; background-color:#f1f1f1; border-radius:15px; padding:20px;" align="center">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" class="img-fluid" />
          <h4 class="text-info">Product name</h4>
          <h4 class="text-danger">€ 0.00</h4>
          <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-conrol" value="1" />
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="Name" />
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="Price" />
          <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="In winkelwagen" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-4">
      <form method="post" action="">
        <div style="border:1px solid #333; background-color:#f1f1f1; border-radius:15px; padding:20px;" align="center">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" class="img-fluid" />
          <h4 class="text-info">Product name</h4>
          <h4 class="text-danger">€ 0.00</h4>
          <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-conrol" value="1" />
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="Name" />
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="Price" />
          <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="In winkelwagen" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-4">
      <form method="post" action="">
        <div style="border:1px solid #333; background-color:#f1f1f1; border-radius:15px; padding:20px;" align="center">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" class="img-fluid" />
          <h4 class="text-info">Product name</h4>
          <h4 class="text-danger">€ 0.00</h4>
          <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-conrol" value="1" />
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="Name" />
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="Price" />
          <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="In winkelwagen" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```